# Scrape repetative HTML into JSON array with Node

Tags: html, node.js, each, cheerio

I'm practicing scraping and I am trying to scrape a list of agents into a JSON array. My code currently only scrapes the last person 4 times.  I'm wondering how to iterate through each class that repeats.

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app     = express();

app.get('/scrape', function(req, res){

char = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x',
'y','z']

url = 'http://www.nhlpa.com/inside-nhlpa/certified-player-agents/find-an-agent?ln=A';

request(url, function(error, response, html){
    if(!error){
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);

        var agent, agency, address, street, city, state, country, zip, deskphone, fax, email, cell;
        var json = { agent : "", agency : "", street : "", city : "", state : "", country : "", zip : "", deskphone : "", fax : "", email : "", cell : ""};
        var jsonarry = []

    $('.inBox').each(function(i, elem) {

        $('.inBodyText').filter(function(){
            var data = $(this);
            agent = data.children().first().text();
            //agency = data.children().last().children().text();

            json.agent = agent;

        })



        $('.inCaption').filter(function(){
            var data = $(this);
            agency =     data.children().children().first().next().text();
            json.agency = agency;
            street =     data.children().children().first().next().next().text();
            json.street = street;
            address =       data.children().children().first().next().next().next().text().replace(/ /g,'');
            address = address.split(",");
            json.city = address[0];
            json.state = address[1]
            json.country = address[2]
            zip =        data.children().children().first().next().next().next().next().text();
            json.zip = zip

            deskphone =  data.children().children().last().prev().prev().prev().text();
            json.deskphone = deskphone
            fax =        data.children().children().last().prev().prev().text();
            json.fax = fax
            email =      data.children().children().last().prev().text();
            json.email = email
            cell =       data.children().children().last().text();
            json.cell = cell
        })
        jsonarry.push(json)
      });
    }



    fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(jsonarry, null, 4), function(err){

    console.log('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output.json file');

})

res.send(html)

    }) ;
})



app.listen('8081')

console.log('Listen on port 8081');

exports = module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Could you try please move your `jsonarry.push(json)` just 1 line up? and see if it change anything

Comment: @VladHolubiev nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is that you're reusing the same `json` variable over an over.

So what happens is that the first time around, you insert the relevant data in that object. You push the object on the array.

On the next iteration, you modify the same variable (so you change the one that is already in the array, since it's the same one), and you push it again.

And so on.

Solution: create a new object each time, simply by moving this line:

```
var json = { agent : "", agency : "", street : "", city : "", state : "", country : "", zip : "", deskphone : "", fax : "", email : "", cell : ""};
```

inside the loop.

#### Update

The second issue is that your lookups of `$('.inCaption')` and `$('.inCaption')` are relative to the whole document, so you get the same result each time (which is actually a list of those elements).

Solution: specify that you want to work relative to the current element, by adding `elem` as the second parameter to those calls: `$('.inCaption', elem)` and `$('.inCaption', elem)`

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't seem to do anything

Comment: Added second issue and solution for that.

Comment: Nice! Thanks, so there were two issues.  I was definitely thinking alongs lines of the second issues, but didn't know what exactly was going on.